# LRM-00101: unknown parameter name '_first_spare_parameter'

Tags: oracle, upgrade, oracle-18c

I am part-way through an upgrade from Oracle 11g to 18c on RedHat.

The Database Upgrade Assistant gives the message:

**Errors encountered during the execution of "Database Components Upgrade".**

**Oracle_Server.log** shows:

```
select count(*) from v$instance
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
select count(*) from v$instance
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
LRM-00101: unknown parameter name '_first_spare_parameter'
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
select status from v$instance
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
```

How can I resolve the issue **LRM-00101: unknown parameter name '_first_spare_parameter'**?

Comment: Remove `_first_spare_parameter` from the parameter file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the spfile create a pfile, which can be edited directly:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
create pfile='/tmp/pfile.ora' from spfile;
exit
```

Edit `/tmp/pfile.ora`, remove `_first_spare_parameter`. Then create the spfile again:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
create spfile from pfile='/tmp/pfile.ora';
```

Now you can try starting your instance.

Above should work in a standard single instance environment, in a customized or clustered environment you may need extra steps.